# Default Content-Type for Mapping Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, content-type, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm working with a data provider for my project that does not adhere to any standards unfortunately, so no content-type specified within the header of the request. Actually it is specified, but with a different key then content-type.

The payload of the POST request is in xml format, so as far as I understand we need to use mapping template to wrap the payload in json object. All this works really great when we specify content-type to be one of the set up types in Integration Request part.

Now to my understanding if content-type is not specified in a request header then it should default to 'application/json' and execute mapping template associated with that type. In our case it behaves like it is ignoring the mapping template, which in turn results with following error returned:

{"Type":"User","message":"Could not parse request body into json."}

Just mention, the request is send for processing to AWS Lambda.

Any ideas how we can get that working ?

Edit: I have confirmed that the default is 'application/json' in case if the Content-Type is not set within the header. In that case I'm assuming what I'm experiencing is a bug.

Comment: If the default content type is application/json, doesn't it follow that the gateway is *expecting* JSON, and rejecting the request because that isn't what the payload is?

Comment: Yes and no. This is no bearing on the mapping template being called or not, it just specifies which one should be called. The mapping template should at least be called. If I explicitly set the Content-Type to application/json then the mapping template is called and the xml content is nicely shaved into an JSON object and all is good. The problem is that when that content-type is missing the default is not called which should be the applicaiton/json. AWS representative on their forum already confirmed that the default should be called. Looks like it might be a bug in AWS.

Comment: Default `Content-Type` can be `'*'`.

Comment: Tried that as well. No happy ending!

Comment: Any new ideas for that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not relying too heavily on the mapping template, you can always use the lambda proxy intergration instead: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html

Effectively this transfers responsibility for parsing the body back onto your lambda function. Your `event` object will now include a `body` string- so regardless of the headers api-gw will simply pass the body to your function to deal with. Which would allow you to parse the body as XML, even though the content-type header is missing/invalid.